# Measurement Protocol, &dp parameter not working

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I use below raw request to `Google Measurement Protocol`.

Same parameters passed to TEST and LIVE tags (except `tid` parameter)

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?tid=UA-12345-67&ea=Purchase&el=Code1&v=1&t=event&ec=OrderBook&cid=0eshxa2zyhqyt3hw54w1qxwn&dp=OrderBook.aspx
```

Strangely when the exact raw request is made for TEST environment is  shows in `GA live events` but not when in LIVE environment

And if I remove `&dp` parameter then it works in both environments. Whats missing?

Comment: One thing that is missing is the slash that usually starts a page path, and while I doubt that this has anything do to with your problem you might consider adding it.

Comment: Does the View for your live environment have any exclude or transformation (eg search & replace) filters applied to it?

Comment: @EikePierstorff ,actually when the / is added , it same

Comment: @vinoaj there are no filters on the view

Comment: Does your live view analytics show the hits in the reports after a day or so? Sometimes hits may not show in realtime reports but then end up later in your processed reports

Comment: @vinoaj i will check this,